# Typescript function where object has a property of type string determined by another parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, keyof

I want to create a TypeScript function that takes an object and a property within that object, for which the value is a `string`. Using `<T, K extends keyof T>` works to make sure only keys of `T` are allowed as values for the property, but I cannot seem to narrow it down so that the key must also point to a property of type `string`. Is this possible?

I tried this:

```
function getKey<T extends {K: string}, K extends keyof T>(item: T, keyProperty: K): string {
     return item[keyProperty];
}
```

But it just says `Type 'T[K]' is not assignable to type 'string'`. Why doesn't the `T extends {K: string}` constraint make sure that `T[K]` is in fact a `string`, or rather, that the supplied `K` must fulfill the condition so that `T[K]` is a `string`?

To be clear, I want to be able to call this function like this:

```
getKey({foo: 'VALUE', bar: 42}, 'foo') => return 'VALUE';

getKey({foo: 'VALUE', bar: 42}, 'bar') => should not be allowed since 'bar' is not a string property of the supplied object

getKey({foo: 'VALUE', bar: 'ANOTHER VALUE'}, 'bar') => return 'ANOTHER VALUE'
```

Comment: The type `{K: string}` corresponds to an object with a key that's literally `"K"`; like `obj.K = "oopsie";`.  You want something like `Record<K, string>` or `{[P in K]: string}`.

Comment: Ah, of course. I will try the `in` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In, `{K: string}`, the `K` in just the name of the [string literal](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) key.  It's the same thing as if you had written `{"K": string}`:

```
type Oops = { "K": string };
// type Oops = { K: string; }
```

Since you want `K` to be the *type* of the key, you need to use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types), which iterates over some union of keys... either `{[P in K]: string}`, or the equivalent `Record<K, string>` using the [`Record<K, T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt):

```
function getKey<T extends { [P in K]: string }, K extends keyof T>(
    item: T,
    keyProperty: K
): string {
    return item[keyProperty]; // no error
}
```

And your calling code behaves (mostly) as you expect:

```
getKey({ foo: 'VALUE', bar: 42 }, 'foo'); // okay
getKey({ foo: 'VALUE', bar: 42 }, 'bar'); // error!
//   ----------------> ~~~
// number is not assignable to string
getKey({ foo: 'VALUE', bar: 'ANOTHER VALUE' }, 'bar'); // okay
```

---

I say "mostly" because it's possible you expect the error in the second line to be on the `'bar'` value passed in for `keyProperty`, whereas what actually happens is that the error is on the `bar` property of the value passed in for `item`.

With a little more finagling you can get that to happen:

```
type KeysMatching<T, V> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? K : never }[keyof T];

function getKey2<T extends { [P in K]: string }, K extends KeysMatching<T, string>>(
    item: T,
    keyProperty: K
): string {
    return item[keyProperty];
}
```

Here we constrain `K` not just to `keyof T`, but to the specific keys of `T` whose values are of type `string`.  We do this with our own `KeysMatching<T, V>` utility type.  This doesn't change what values will end up being valid, but it does shift where the compiler complains when something is invalid:

```
getKey2({ foo: 'VALUE', bar: 42 }, 'foo'); 
getKey2({ foo: 'VALUE', bar: 42 }, 'bar'); // error!
//  -----------------------------> ~~~~~
//  "bar" is not "foo"
getKey2({ foo: 'VALUE', bar: 'ANOTHER VALUE' }, 'bar');
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBA8g9mAzlAvFA3lARAaSwLikWACcBLAOwHMoBfAbgFgAoAelalElgWTUxyFi5avTosWAMwCuFAMbAycClCoRgOCCAA8AFSgQAHsAgUAJskwBtAApRKUHAF0hpSjVoAaRweOmLUADWWnCSULoAfAAULFBx9iYAtoS6nrHxwSA2JAgQJKCEOCwAlK4iNOjpcSTq0iQqZElWmdm5+SBOYiy0EsxqGlpRmJJwcIQA5ABqAIIAMgCqAKLj3gBGAIYkhAAsAEx03uMjcOPFTH3qmiBDUMcTMwvLa5s7+15Q4xskp2LsBiQ5EgAQhYfziAFpIVDoTDwREoAA-JGgjgUaSJVZ5ezIChwYBQdaIRBkKgUdarAA20GAcCIbmoLH6Vxudw+DyWKygXwm0wAcjBdAAJRYAJSg7OWBw+Xx+vRYXGgV0QAFl1sA5AALdx6byTeH8KBWHD2FSZULhFzhI1OXwmczISZQAD8PkIFAgADcsbRmiEwrpOr0ZPJFMpVJctLs9Lb-JZDXYHM4yu4pcajHaAkrVeqtdQdXTyhFolUEhBkuE0sx4kEtK1IO1CiVk9QMCWasA6g0mi0cvXQIHmD1mIyIyBdizRvc5hznlsoHspUdRj8oCOBmOJ2M2dOnlyXvO3ocZWcoH88oCQWwOFBYbe73f4Uinyi4lgvlhsVBcfisMcsGurnHYZJ23R5OW5D4+QFYUxQlcZF2Pc4gA)

Answer (score 1):

```
function getKey<T>(item: T, keyProperty: {[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? K : never}[keyof T]): string {
    return <string> <unknown> item[keyProperty];
}
```

Little bit bulky, but meh.. it works. :)